# How do $K_i$ of SO(4) transform like a vector under the SO(3) subalgebra

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory, lie-groups, lie-algebras, rotations

A groups and representations book states:

$[J_i, K_j] = i \epsilon_{ijk} K_k$ tells us that the $K_i$s tarnsform like a vector under the SO(3) subalgebra of SO(4). As an exercise, show that, for example:

$$e^{i \phi J_3} K_1 e^{i \phi J_3} = cos(\phi) K_1 + sin(\phi) K_3$$

I'm confused by exactly what connection they are making here. A vector wouldn't transform like that, in fact it can't even satisfy the above matrix-vector-matrix multiplication. Also how exactly does this come from the commutation relation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start by defining $k_1(\phi)=e^{-i\phi J_3}K_1e^{i\phi J_3}$ and $k_2(\phi)=e^{-i\phi J_3}K_2e^{i\phi J_3}$.

Then
$$ \frac{d}{d\phi}k_1=e^{-i\phi J_3}(-iJ_3)K_1e^{i\phi J_3}+e^{-i\phi J_3}K_1(iJ_3)e^{i\phi J_3}=k_2(\phi)$$
and
$$ \frac{d}{d\phi}k_2=e^{-i\phi J_3}(-iJ_3)K_2e^{i\phi J_3}+e^{-i\phi J_3}K_2(iJ_3)e^{i\phi J_3}=-k_1(\phi)$$
(notice how a negative sign in one of the exponents is crucial), where we have used the commutation relation.

These two equations give you the solutions
$$k_1(\phi)=K_1\cos\phi+K_2\sin\phi$$
and
$$k_2(\phi)=K_2\cos\phi-K_1\sin\phi.$$

Now, this is "like" the behaviour of a vector, if you write $(K_1,K_2,K_3)$ and rotate this by $\phi$ around the third axis. It is often the case in mathematics that how something *transforms* is actually more important than what it *is*.

Comment: This almost makes sense. But why is the transformation of surrounding the matrix (or element of a vector or matrices) by those exponents obvious?

Comment: As in, the K’s only transform “like a vector under rotations” if you define ‘a rotation’ like this for the K’s (as opposed to just multiplication by a rotation matrix for vectors). Why is this form intuitive?

Comment: Is the idea something like: the right exponential rotates a vector in the new co-ordinate system back to the old one, then K1 acts as usual, then the left exponential rotates the result back into the new co-ordinate system. If so, it seems to me like the negative should be in the other exponential

Comment: Yes, the idea is as you say. To transform a vector by a transformation $M$, you multiply it by $M$. To transform an operator $K$ by a transformation $M$, you do $MKM^{-1}$

Comment: Amazing thanks. Any intuition for why the negative is on the left not right exponential then? Isn’t the positive exponential here the usual rotation matrix therefore M in your formula

Comment: Okay I think I'm happy now (I always get confused with passive transformations).